# Adding Views to the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl via a Region of a Scoped RegionManager

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, region-management

I am trying to populate the `ItemsSource` of a `ComboBox` (a derivative of `ItemsControl`) via a region.

**View**

The scoped `RegionManager` (found on the View Model) is assigned to the view via `prism:RegionManager.RegionManager="{Binding RegionManager}"`.

***MainWindow.xaml***

```
<Window x:Class="Applications.Testing.Wpf.RegionCreationTester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Applications.Testing.Wpf.RegionCreationTester"
    xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    prism:RegionManager.RegionManager="{Binding RegionManager}"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static local:RegionNames.itemsControlRegion}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
namespace Applications.Testing.Wpf.RegionCreationTester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, IModelled<MainWindowViewModel>
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return (MainWindowViewModel)DataContext;
            }
            set
            {
                DataContext = value;
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel.PopulateItemsControl();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

The view model is assigned to the view's DataContext via `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`.

***MainWindowViewModel.cs***

```
namespace Applications.Testing.Wpf.RegionCreationTester
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the <see cref="RegionManager"/> scoped to this control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Exists so that child controls can register regions for their own child controls which are also child controls in this control.</remarks>
        public RegionManager RegionManager { get; } = new RegionManager();

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds some child views to the <see cref="RegionNames.itemsControlRegion"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Normally these views would be resolved using an IoC container but this have been omitted for brevity.</remarks>
        public void PopulateItemsControl()
        {
            var region = RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.itemsControlRegion];
            region.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Item #1" });
            region.Add(new Button { Content = "Item #2" });
        }
    }
}
```

**RegionNames.cs**

```
namespace Applications.Testing.Wpf.RegionCreationTester
{
    public static class RegionNames
    {
        public const string itemsControlRegion = "collectionRegion";
    }
}
```

**Bootstrapper**

***App.xaml***

```
<Application x:Class="Applications.Testing.Wpf.RegionCreationTester.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"/>
```

***App.xaml.cs***

```
namespace Applications.Testing.Wpf.RegionCreationTester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            new RegionCreationTesterBootstrapper().Run();
        }
    }
}
```

***RegionCreationTesterBootstrapper.cs***

```
namespace Applications.Testing.Wpf.RegionCreationTester
{
    public class RegionCreationTesterBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
            => new MainWindow();

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();

            (Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Once all the region population has occurred and the application is about to run I get a `Prism.Regions.UpdateRegionsException` containing an InnerException with the message `"Region with the given name is already registered: collectionRegion"` on the line in `App` of `new RegionCreationTesterBootstrapper().Run()`.  The last line in my code I am able to get a breakpoint hit for is the `new MainWindow()` in `CreateShell` after the call to the constructor for MainWindow has exited.  Why am I being told the region is already registered when I am only trying to register it once?  I have set breakpoints in the MainWindow's constructor to indeed confirm that it only being created once and even if it weren't, the `RegionManager` to which it is scoped should prevent this exception from occurring.  What have I missed?

**UPDATE**

I have just commented out the code within `PopulateItemsControl` and found that the exception is thrown even if only one view is added to the region and stranger still, if no views are added to the region but the region is accessed (as done in the line: `var region = RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.itemsControlRegion];`).  Therefore the issue is now to do with accessing an existing region on a scoped RegionManager for View Injection in order to add views to it; I'm not sure why accessing a region from the RegionManager would change its state, this seems like a bug in Prism or perhaps something to do with lazy enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are doing it twice, you're just not aware. When you set `RegionName` attached property on your ComboBox, an event hanler that will create the region with given name is attached (that's static part of `RegionManager`). When the instance of `RegionManager` you instantiated in your VM tries to access the region collection, indexer first calls a *static* method on `RegionManager` class that raises the event. The global `RegionManager` instance that got the task of creating the region (when you used `RegionName` attached property) has not finished it's job - window hasn't been loaded when you try to access the region with your instance, the handler has not been removed and it's called again. If you called your `PopulateItemsControl` method after the window has loaded (say in MainWindow's Loaded event handler), you wouldn't get the exception, but your code would not work as you expect. That is because your instance of `RegionManager` is not "handling" your collectionRegion, global `RegionManager` is.

#### Injecting RegionManager instance

If you need a `RegionManager` instance in your VM, use constructor injection.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IRegionManager rm;

    public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager manager)
    {
        this.rm = manager;
    }

    public void PopulateItemsControl()
    {
        var region = rm.Regions[RegionNames.itemsControlRegion];
        region.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Item #1" });
    }
}
```

Dependency injection container (Unity or whatever you're using) will resolve `IRegionManager` instance when creating the VM (PRISM is doing that job for you anyway, you're not instantiating it yourself).

#### Region scopes

`RegionManager` keeps a collection of regions and does not allow regions with same names. So, unless your window is going to have multiple of those ComboBoxes that all have a region named `collectionRegion`, the `RegionManager` (the global one) is fine. If your `collectionRegion` is going to have instances of same view class, that all define another region within itself, then you need region scopes - `RegionManager` instances with their own scope for those views. In that case,  the `Add` method can create local instance of `RegionManager` for that view:

```
IRegion collectionRegion = this.regionManager.Regions["collectionRegion"];
bool makeRegionManagerScope = true;
IRegionManager localRegionManager =
    collectionRegion.Add(view, null, makeRegionManagerScope);
```

Comment: In my actual solution the `ComboBox` is part of a custom control which can appear in multiple places in the `MainWindow.xaml`; since this custom control is not a collection control itself, it is registered using view discovery instead of view injection.  Will I have to switch to using view injection for this as well in order to scope each instance's `RegionManager` to prevent a naming conflict on `collectionRegion` itself?  If I could keep the `RegionManager` out of the view models that would be ideal but the scoping seems to be necessary to allow for indiscriminately re-usable controls.

Comment: @Sphynx From what I know, you can't get scoped `RegionManager`s using view discovery. Having `RegionManager` instance in your VM is common, as it is needed for navigation (commands eventually call `RegionManager.RequestNavigate`). If your custom controls are going to be added to a region (some ItemsControl) within MainWindow, then you'll need view injection. If you'll have, for example 3 of your controls on specific locations in MainWindow, then they could have different region names (expose a DP on your control for region name, bind there from the template).

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding how to get the `RegionManager` used in the view model into the view; should I still be using `RegionManager.RegionManager="{Binding MyRegionManager}"` for the control containing the `ComboBox` if it needs to be scoped?  If I were to inject that custom control into `MainWindow.xaml` using something like `myCustomControlRegion.Add(view, null, true)` then how would I get the newly-scoped `RegionManager` back onto that view's view model in order to call `collectionRegion.Add(view, null, true)` each time the collection in that control is changed?

Comment: @Sphynx When you use `var localRm = myCustomControlRegion.Add(view, null, true);`, the `view` already has it's `RegionManager` attached property set to `localRm` (you can check that using static `RegionManager.GetRegionManager(view)`), so you don't need to bind anything. About the other thing, I'm not sure if I'm following you. When you're injecting the `view`, you have access to it's VM `var vm =
 (someViewModel)view.DataContext`. So, `vm.RegionManager = localRm`, or something like that.